# Clipped Bing Map won't refresh in a ScrollViewer?

Tags: windows-phone-7.1, bing-maps, windows-phone-7

I have a bing map with this clip:

```
<my:Map.Clip>
     <RectangleGeometry RadiusX="15" RadiusY="15" Rect="0,0,450,250" />
</my:Map.Clip>
```

The map is in a ScrollViewer somewhere at the bottom and only half of it is visible.
The problem is that when I scroll up to reveal the entire map, the part of the map that was not visible is now black.

This problem doesn't occur when I don't have a clip on my map. It's rendered correctly.
So is this a bug in the control or am I doing something wrong?
Anyone had this issue before?

Update: I have made a small sample project to demonstrate this: [link](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/20848147/Stack%20Overflow/BingMapClipIssueDemo.zip). Also, while doing this I also noticed that the problem only occurs when the map control is inside a grid. If I place it straight in the ScrollViewer it works just fine.

Update: Setting a fixed height for the grid row doesn't help. Also, putting the grid + map inside a stackpanel and then inside a scrollviewer doesn't work. Any of you found anything to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On looking at your code, this has nothing to do with the map capturing the gestures rather than the `ScrollViewer`, the map maintains its original clip regardless of where the user initiates their scroll.

The reason for this behaviour is that the `Map` Silverlight control (and the `WebBrowser` control too) include a native rendering component. For example the `WebBrowser` has a `TileHost` as described [in this article](http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2011/11/suppressing-zoom-and-scroll-interactions-in-the-windows-phone-7-browser-control/). For this reason, various Silverlight framework effects cannot be applied to the map, for example RenderTransforms.

To solve you issue you are going to have to force the map to re-render itself when the user scrolls. To do this, I locate the `ScrollViewer` vertical `ScrollBar` using [Linq-to-VisualTree](http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2010/03/linq-to-visual-tree/), then as the user scrolls apply a very very small zoom to the map. This will cause it to re-render:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls.Primitives;
using LinqToVisualTree;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;

namespace BingMapClipIssueDemo
{
    public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        // Constructor
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(ContentPanel_Loaded);
        }

        void ContentPanel_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

          ScrollBar verticalScroll = ContentPanel.Descendants<ScrollBar>()
                          .Cast<ScrollBar>()
                          .Where(sb => sb.Orientation == System.Windows.Controls.Orientation.Vertical)
                          .Single();

          verticalScroll.ValueChanged += (s, e2) =>
            {
              map.ZoomLevel = map.ZoomLevel + 0.00001;
            };

        }
    }
}
```

Just drop the code above into your example and it should work.

Comment: Interesting. This might actually work. I'll check it out tomorrow when I get at my PC and let you know how it works.

Comment: Ok, so I tried using your solution but unfortunately I was not able to use LinqToVisualTree in my WP7 project.

Comment: Why not? Just cut and paste the code, or download it as part of wp7contrib and off you go.

Comment: Right. Got it working. I think I was actually importing the wrong files. So, thanks for the answer. Not exactly what I was looking for but it's better than nothing. If I don't get a better solution by this evening the (very small) bounty is yours. Thx again for the help.

Answer (score 2):

You should not include a Bing Map control within a ScrollViewer or Pivot, Panorama or any other control that captures pan / scroll gestures. This will lead to a very poor user-experience because the user will not know whether the gesture is going to be captured by the map or the hosting control. What I think is happening is that when you scroll, you are not scrolling the ScrollViewer, rather, you are panning the map.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't think you understood my problem. The problem isn't about who captures the scroll, but the fact that when I scroll down in the ScrollViewer to reveal the entire map, the bottom part of the map remains black, it's not rendered. I have made a small sample project to demonstrate this: [link](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/20848147/Stack%20Overflow/BingMapClipIssueDemo.zip). Also, while doing this I also noticed that the problem only occurs when the map control is inside a grid. If I place it straight in the ScrollViewer it works just fine.

Comment: Colin is still absolutely right, you ***should not*** place a Bing Map control inside a ScrollViewer. End of story.

Comment: End of story for you maybe, not for me. I need that map in a scrollviewer. You are not supposed to be able to interact with it anyway, it's there only to display a pushpin so there is no problem regarding who captures pan / scroll gestures.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the Static Bing Maps API instead of the Bing Map control if you don't want the user to interact with the Map

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701724.aspx